# Cisco swtich stacked NTP configure

Tags: cisco, switch, ntp

I have two cisco switches (WS-C3850-12XS-E) stacked by stack cable. I want to configure ntp on them. 
How to configure ntp on those about time synchronization?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You configure a stack as a single switch, not two separate switches. Simply log into the stack and configure NTP:

> **ntp server** *ip-address* [**version** *number*] [**key** *key-id*] [**source** *interface-type interface-number*] [**prefer**]

There are other options and configurations for NTP, but the above command will configure the switch stack to use a particular NTP server.

You can refer to *[Basic System Management Configuration Guide, Cisco IOS XE Release 2, Setting Time and Calendar Services](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/bsm/configuration/xe-2/bsm-xe-2-book/bsm-time-calendar-set.html)* for more information.